# index.js and main.css not resolving on different base url

Tags: angular, typescript

We have a use case that our `Angular2` application is available at `/pro/`. This makes our base href: `<base href="/pro/">`. This works perfectly for routing, assets etc. But the `main.css` and `index.js` from the `index.html` cannot be found and result in a 404 because it looks for them at `/pro/main.css`.

I cannot seem to find a way to fix the inclusion of these files. Anyone here who might have a solution?

- We are using `webpack`.
- We are using `RC4` version of `Angular2`.

Our `index.html` looks something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>-</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="-">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/pro/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        Loading ...
    </app>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in the css and index.js being loaded from `/pro/main.css` - this is the behavior we want. Unfortunatly it gives me a `404`.

I've set the `baseUrl` in `main.node.ts`:

```
// the polyfills must be the first thing imported in node.js
// import 'angular2-universal/polyfills'; // polyfills are moved to server.ts

// Angular 2 Universal
import {
  REQUEST_URL,
  ORIGIN_URL,
  NODE_LOCATION_PROVIDERS,
  NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ExpressEngineConfig
} from 'angular2-universal';

import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

// Application
import {App} from './app/app.component';
import {routes} from './app/app.routes';

export function ngApp(req, res) {
  let baseUrl = '/pro/';
  let url = req.originalUrl || '/';

  let config: ExpressEngineConfig = {
    directives: [
      App
    ],
    platformProviders: [
      {provide: ORIGIN_URL, useValue: 'http://localhost:3000'},
      {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl},
    ],
    providers: [
      {provide: REQUEST_URL, useValue: url},
      NODE_HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      provideRouter(routes),
      NODE_LOCATION_PROVIDERS
    ],
    async: true,
    preboot: false // { appRoot: 'app' } // your top level app component selector
  };

  res.render('index', config);
}
```

And the routing/static serving is done like this:

```
app.use('/pro/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'), {maxAge: 30}));
app.get('/pro', ngApp);
app.get('/pro/about', ngApp);
app.get('/pro/about/*', ngApp);
```

Comment: Could you add how you insert the links to your stiles file? Are you using SystemJS/webpack?

Comment: I've updated the question with additional information. Please ask if you are missing anything - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<base href="...">` you can also provide

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
```

```
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/pro/' }
```

to only specify it for the router.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this is not related to Angular. As the specification for `<base>` says:

> The HTML  element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document.
>   [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Try `href="/main.css"` (or `../main.css`).